# Prove that $\mathbb{|Q| = |Q\times Q|}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I have this problem:

> Prove that $\mathbb{|Q| = |Q\times Q|}$

I know that $\mathbb Q$ is countably infinite.

But then how can I prove that $\mathbb{|Q\times Q|}$ is countably infinite?

Thanks you!

Comment: you mean cartesian product?

Comment: See also: [Prove that $|\mathbb{Q}| = |\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2323279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever proof you have that $\mathbb Q$ is countably infinite probably relies on a mapping between elements of $\mathbb Q$ and elements of $\mathbb {Z \times Z}$. But to say that $\mathbb Q$ is countably infinite is to put it in correspondence with $\mathbb Z$. Use this fact, then repeat the original proof.

Answer (score 2):

Use $\mathbb{|N\times N|=|N|}$ and $\mathbb{|N|=|Q|}$.